# What's the difference between these 2 declarations in c?

Tags: c, syntax

```
typedef int F1(int x);

int F1(int x);
```

Seems the same to me,either with `typedef` or not..

Comment: In this case it is the same because even if you dont mention the return type,the default return type is int.But this this will be different when using a different data type .http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/31059

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`typedef` doesn't declare a variable; it declares a type.

After you say:

```
typedef int F1(int x);
```

later in your code you can have this:

```
F1 myfunction;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int myfunction(int x);
```

Comment: So I can't use `F1 myfunction` if not using `typedef`?

Comment: @wp2 -- exactly.  Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05w82thz(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 6):

```
typedef int F1(int x);
```

You define a function type F1 which is function taking a integer as argument and returning an integer

```
int F1(int x);
```

You define a function which is called F1

Comment: The difference is clearer when writing: "typedef int (*F1)(int x);"

Comment: @eylam - The two are not equivalent. Yours declares a function pointer type. The original declares a function type.

Comment: @Manoj: I know but they are generally used for function pointer. That's why i did put the parenthesis.

Comment: @onemasse - `typedef int functype(int);` and `typedef int (*funcptr)(int);` are different. `functype f;` declares a function `f` while `funcptr fp = f;` declares a function pointer `fp` that points to `f`. Expand them inline and see the difference.

Comment: @Manoj: it was a little bit confusing so I did delete the `(pointer)` part. Thx for your intervention